# Did demons also have a Varna system?

Tags: varna, rakshasa, varnashrama, daitya, demon

Is there any reference of a demon or rakshasa having a varna? Was the Varna system followed by Rakshasas?

Comment: That's an interesting question.

Comment: Well I think yes they do have varna system

Comment: Raksasa is a group/ clan of entities. Varna system is based on occupation chosen by individual. It is possible that they may have a Varna system within their own clan.